# every sequence has a monotone subsequence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I am trying to prove this theorem "every sequence has a monotone subsequence"

I found this proof

> **Proof:** Let us call a positive integer $n$ a *peak of the sequence* if $m > n  \implies x_n > x_m$  i.e., if  $x_n$ is greater than every subsequent term in the sequence.
>
> Suppose first that the sequence has infinitely many peaks, $n_1 < n_2 < n_3 < … < n_j < …$. Then the subsequence $\{x_{n_j}\}_j$  corresponding to these peaks is monotonically decreasing, and we are done.
>
> So suppose now that there are only finitely many peaks, let $N$ be the last peak and set $n_1 = N + 1$.
>
> Then $n_1$ is not a peak, since $n_1 > N$, which implies the existence of an $n_2 > n_1$ with  $x_{n_2} \geq x_{n_1}.$  Again, as $n_2 > N$ it is not a peak, hence there is $n_3 > n_2$ with $x_{n_3} \geq x_{n_2}.$  Repeating this process leads to an infinite non-decreasing subsequence  $x_{n_1} \leq x_{n_2} \leq x_{n_3} \leq \ldots$ as desired.

My question is about this part "So suppose now that there are only finitely many peaks"

is $0$ peak valid? for example the sequence $\{\dfrac{n}{n+1}\}$ has no peaks.

Comment: Thank you,
the first term is 1/2 ,
the second term is 2/3,
therefore $x_n$ < $x_m$, the first term is not peak

Comment: What does it mean for a sequence to have no peaks?

Comment: I understand that: The sequence is a increasing sequence

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Zero peak is valid and should be addressed.  If a sequence has no peaks, then for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$, there exists $m > n$ such that $x_n \leq x_m$.  Applying this to $n=1$ gives $n_2 > 1$, such that $x_{n_2} \geq x_1$.  Applying to $n=n_2$ gives $n_3 > n_2$ such that $x_{n_3} \geq x_{n_2}$.  In this way we get an increasing sequence $\left\{ n_k \right\}$ (here $n_1 = 1$), such that $\left\{ x_{n_k} \right\}$ is monotone.

---

EDIT: It looks like this is equivalent to setting $n_1=1$ if there are no peaks, and applying the same logic as the proof you wrote.

Comment: It doesn't need to be dealt with separately, you can just set $N=-1$ (assuming your sequences start with $n=0$) and the proof works just fine.

Comment: Yes, thank you :)

Comment: @NajibIdrissi But if we set N = -1, wouldn't this mean that the last peak is -1? How does this make sense?

Comment: Instead of thinking that the value of N means "the last peak occurs here", think that it means "no peaks occur after this index".  Setting the value N=-1 when there are no peaks is just a convenient way to avoid splitting the case of zero peaks into a separate thing.

Answer (score 2):

Consider any sequence $(x_n).$

A "peak" element is an element such that all elements $x_i$ that succeed it in the sequence are no greater than it. In other words, an element $x_p$ is a "peak" element if for all $i > p_1,$ it is the case that $x_{p_1} \geq x_i.$

In the sequence $(x_n),$ either there are finitely many peaks, or there are infinitely many.

If there are finitely many, then there is a peak element $x_p$ that appears last. Then, for all $i \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $i > p,$ there exists some $M \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $M > i$ and $x_M > x_i.$ In such a case, there clearly exists a monotone *increasing* subsequence $(x_{n_i}).$

If there are infinitely many peaks, then there clearly exists a monotone *decreasing* subsequence,

$$x_{p_1}, x_{p_2}, x_{p_3}, \ldots$$

where $x_{p_1} \geq x_{p_2} \geq x_{p_3} \geq \cdots$ are all peak elements.

Hence, any sequence has some subsequence that is monotone, whether increasing or decreasing.